# Submit event doesn't work when specifying with class

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a view which has the "el" set to the form id. I have two buttons in the form, one for submit and one for clear. I cannot figure out how to set an event for each button. For example when I set the events as follows they will not work:

Form Template:

```
    <form id="addTask" action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your new task"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add Task"/>
        <input type="submit" id="clear" value="Clear" />
    </form>
```

Form View:

```
    App.Views.AddTask = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#addTask',

        events: {
            'submit .edit': 'submit',
            'submit .clear': 'clear'
        },

        submit: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var newTaskTitle = $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();
            var task = new App.Models.Task({ title: newTaskTitle });

            this.collection.add(task);
        },

        clear: function() {
            // do some stuff
        }
    });
```

When I use the below syntax for the "click" event in another view it works.

```
    events: {
        'click .delete': 'destroy',
        'click .edit': 'edit'
    },
```

I have Googled and cannot find an answer. Funny thing is I found a tutorial where this syntax is used with a submit event:

http://dailyjs.com/2013/01/31/backbone-tutorial-10/

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just few line of the code won't let us know what actually happen there

Comment: I apologize for not adding more code. I edited my post and added more code.

Answer (score 0):

The submit event is triggered on the form itself, in your case your "el", not the clicked button.

```
events: {
    'submit': 'onSubmit'
}
```

Would work, but you wouldn't be able to know which button has been clicked.
If you have to submit button, I guess the correct way to do it would be to have two forms.

Let me know if that helps!

Edit:

If you don't want to change your form:

Form Template:

```
<form id="addTask" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your new task"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add Task"/>
    <input type="submit" id="clear" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

Form View:

```
App.Views.AddTask = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#addTask',

    events: {
        'submit': 'submit',
        'click #clear': 'clear'
    },

    submit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newTaskTitle = $(e.currentTarget).find('input[type=text]').val();
        var task = new App.Models.Task({ title: newTaskTitle });

        this.collection.add(task);
    },

    clear: function() {
        // do some stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: I added more code. I guess I was trying to attach the event to the parent element. Kind of dumb that I thought I could do that. Is there a way to do this using event delegation?

Comment: Hello Gmajoulet, can you please look at the code above. I added the form. I guess it feels odd to make individual forms for each button. Is there another way to deal with this?